# How can I speed up a video without pitch distortion in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, video, ffmpeg

What I'd like to achieve is getting the same effect as I get with (assuming 1.7x speed up) :

```
mplayer -af scaletempo -speed 1.7 myvideo.mp4
```

This command gives me exactly what I want, but I need to save the result in file somehow.

What I don't want to get is this:

```
mplayer -vf scale -speed 1.7 myvideo.mp4
```

I need this to be done in file (file has to be recoded) because I have to play it outside Linux box.

CLI is preferable, because I want to make it in script. Googled around a lot and found lots of suggestions - ffmpeg, mencoder and many funny exotic uncompilable tools, nothing gives me the exact result. Actually almost nothing of this works (I guess it worked in sometime, long long ago).

Unfortunately I upgraded and use Ubuntu 13.04 and it seems that almost all solutions do not work in this version ;(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## setpts & atempo filters

Examples using `ffmpeg` with the [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) and [atempo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atempo) filters:

#### Fast motion

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS/2[v];[0:a]atempo=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output
```

#### Slow motion

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS/0.5[v];[0:a]atempo=0.5[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output
```

Range for atempo value is 0.5-100.

## setpts & rubberband filters

Alternatively you can use the [rubberband](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rubberband) filter instead of atempo, and it may sound better, but your `ffmpeg` will need to be compiled with `--enable-librubberband`. You can refer to `ffmpeg -filters` to see if you can use it.

#### Fast motion

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS/2[v];[0:a]rubberband=tempo=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output
```

#### Slow motion

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS/0.5[v];[0:a]rubberband=tempo=0.5[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output
```

Comment: you literally saved me. Didn't even know that ffmpeg in Ubuntu is something ancient.
I used static build, because there is no ppa or deb for 13.04 and compiling looks really painful.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Weirdly I found `rubberband` to be worse than `atempo` at the same tempo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Video:

```
mkfifo stream.yuv
mplayer -vf scale -speed 1.7 -vo yuv4mpeg source.avi

cat stream.yuv | yuv2lav -o result.avi
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i source.avi -filter "setpts=PTS/1.7" result.avi
```

Audio:

```
mplayer -vf scale -speed 1.7 -vo null -ao pcm -ao pcm:file=result.wav source.avi
```

Result files: result.avi, result.wav